# Updating an APK

Tags: android, apk, auto-update

We have an internal app that checks for updates when launched.  It is not released on Play Store because it is for internal use only.

The update code below was working fine on my test device (API 23).  However I have recently released an update which downloads on the test device but reports:

> Parse Error - There was a problem while parsing the package

On my own device (API 24) the app downloads the app and then crashes.

```
public class UpdateApp extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {
    private Context context;
    public void setContext(Context contextf){
        context = contextf;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(arg0[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.connect();

            File file = context.getCacheDir();
            file.mkdirs();
            outputFile = new File(file, "update.apk");
            if(outputFile.exists()){
                outputFile.delete();
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();
            outputFile.setReadable(true, false);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(outputFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            Toast.makeText(context, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

On both devices the updated APK is downloaded before either throwing an error (API 23) or crashing (API 24).  I do not understand how the app can just crash as all the code is in a `try` block which has a `catch` for the `Throwable` class so it should `catch` all errors and exceptions!

The following is the `logcat` output from my API 24 device whilst updating after the file is downloaded.  Other than pointing to the problem being with the `AysncTask` class, I cannot work out anything useful from this.

```
2018-11-04 16:47:27.593 966-1017/? E/PROXIMITY: ProximitySensor: unknown event (type=3, code=0)
2018-11-04 16:47:27.704 23431-23476/uk.co.letsdelight.letsdelight E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: uk.co.letsdelight.letsdelight, PID: 23431
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:208)
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:122)
        at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:351)
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:106)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:265)
        at uk.co.letsdelight.letsdelight.Update$UpdateApp.doInBackground(Update.java:123)
        at uk.co.letsdelight.letsdelight.Update$UpdateApp.doInBackground(Update.java:83)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
2018-11-04 16:47:27.716 966-989/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity uk.co.letsdelight.letsdelight/.MainActivity
2018-11-04 16:47:27.745 966-23481/? W/AES: Exception Log handling...
```

What else can I do to try to resolve this problem and perhaps make the code more robust so that we do not have issues with further updates?

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Replace your `Toast` with something else. You cannot show a `Toast` on a background thread, which is what the error message is telling you (`Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`). A typical solution, given that you are still using `AsyncTask`, is to hold onto the `Exception` in a field in the `AsyncTask`, then do something with it in `onPostExecute()`, as that is executed on the main application thread.

Step #2: Always log exceptions. At minimum, you should be logging to LogCat. If you have integrated ACRA, Crashlytics, or similar solutions, you should be taking steps to ensure that your exceptions get reported there as well. Right now, your `catch` block is *only* attempting to show a `Toast`, which means you have no way of knowing what the specific problem is (e.g., lack of connectivity).

Step #3: One certain problem on Android 7.0+ is that you cannot use `Uri.fromFile()` very well, as `file` `Uri` values are banned. On those devices, use `FileProvider` to make the APK available to the installer, and use `FileProvider.getUriForFile()` to get the `Uri` to put in your `Intent`. Unfortunately, on Android 6.0 and older devices, you *cannot* use `FileProvider`, as the installer will not support `content` `Uri` values. So, you will need to detect your version (`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`) and use the right `Uri` based on version.

Comment: I've adding some logging to track the start and end of the file download.  These get logged as expected.   I have also adapted the `catch` block so it captures the `Exception` in field and logs `Throwable.toString()` - but this is not being written to the LogCat.
This suggests to me that the problem is not with the update code but with the APK to install.  But if I install this manually, it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` happens in AsyncTasks because you are calling `execute` in a background thread.
you can attach a debugger and check if you are executing this asyncTask in background or not. you can use Evaluator to get value of `Thread.currentThread().getId()` if it returns 1 it means you are on the main thread if not, try to call execute in main thread of your app